# Remove chkconfig header from output

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

On my CentOS machine I wrote a script which tells me whether a service is installed or not.
Here is the script

```
count=$(chkconfig --list | grep -c "$1")
if [ $count = 0 ]; then
    echo "False"
else
    echo "True"
fi
```

The problem is that the output of the command always includes the starting lines of the `chkconfig` output. For example here is the output of `script.sh network`

```
[root@vm ~]# ./script.sh network

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

True
```

It seems that the count variable correctly contains the count of grep occurrences but the script will always output the chkconfig header lines, even though I echo only "True" or "False" in the script.

Why does this happen? And how to hide those lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `chkconfig --list` initially returns a header through `stderr`. Just silence it by using `2>/dev/null`:

```
count=$(chkconfig --list 2>/dev/null | grep -c "$1")
#                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note also that the whole `if / else` block can be reduced to a mere:

```
chkconfig --list 2>/dev/null | grep -q "$1" && echo "True" || echo "False"
```

Since we use the `-q` option of `grep` which (from `man grep`) does *exit immediately with zero status if any match is found*.

Comment: Perfect. I tested this equivalent (but less elegant) solution, just for fun.

`chkconfig --list 2>/dev/null | grep -c "$1" > /dev/null && echo "True" || echo "False"`

Comment: Yep this is also fine, even though the second `>/dev/null` is not necessary because `grep -c` is unlikely to return any stderr on such pipe.

Comment: I put the `>/dev/null` because the `grep -c "$1"` will output the count of occurrences otherwise

Comment: you taught me this very useful trick and save me a lot of time in attempts :)