# In Bash, how can I check the version of Artistic Style?

Tags: bash, version, indentation, astyle

I am writing a portable procedure (i.e. I am not using `dpkg`) in a Bash script that ensures that certain program versions are available. I can get the version of `indent` in the following way:

```
version_indent="$(echo "$(indent --version)" | cut -d" " -f3)"
```

I don't understand why I can't get the version of `astyle` in a similar way:

```
version_astyle="$(echo "$(astyle --version)" | cut -d" " -f4)"
```

When I do the former, I get the actual version; when I do the latter, I get the full string returned by `astyle` printed to the terminal and nothing saved to the variable. What's going wrong?

Comment: What does the output of `astyle --version` look  like?

Comment: Probably `astyle --version` returns the result via stderr, not stdout. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694394/1983854 for someting similar. Basically, just redirect stderr to stdin by saying `astyle --version 2>&1`.

Comment: Sounds like @fedorqui is onto something there. Also I think you can change `echo "$(astyle --version)"` to just `astyle --version`.

Comment: @TomFenech in fact I was astonished checking how uncanonical the output of `--version` is. Some send it through `stderr` and some through `stdout`. Uhms, not nice.

Comment: The `echo $(...)` wrapping is entirely pointless (and costly).

Comment: @TomFenech This seems to work for me: `version_astyle="$(astyle --version 2>&1 | cut -d" " -f4)"` Is this the most reasonable approach?

Comment: @d3pd looks good to me

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/why-does-java-version-go-to-stderr